# Why do media queries show different looks across different website responsiveness testing with same resolutions

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am running into some visual differences when writing media queries and testing it across a resoultion of 1366 x 768 and am using another monitor with its resolution settings at 1366 x 768, and I also check it on a couple other "test your website responsiveness" and tried two of them to compare with my other monitor and they all look different.

The media query I am using is

```
@media screen and (max-height: 768px){
    #AttachMods.on-dock {
        width: 265px !important;
    }

    #AttachMods.on-dock #treelist {
        height: 100px !important;
    }

    #AttachMods.on-dock #TreeSelectItems {
        height: 100px !important;
    }

    #AttachMods.on-dock #ImagePath {
        height: 122px !important;
    }
}
```

here is how it looks on my monitor that I set to 1366x768

[image: monitor]

Here is how it looks on my laptop, 1920x1080, but using a website responsiveness tester, set at 1366x768

[image: RDC]

and here is a different one using another responsiveness tester set at 1366x768

[image: SF]

My question is why is this and without having a bunch of different devices, which one is the true representation of the media query?

Comment: i believe this has to do with `px` vs `ems`. I dont have the link of a discussion on this off the top of my head but it's worth looking into